# h2 tag font size being rewriten by browser

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have an h2 element with a class and proper font size styles. Its doing really strange on MAC desktop's Chrome, as inside the h2 element  tags have being printed, and it uses my global styles "*".
How can I fix it? Here is my original code:

```css
* {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2.ttl {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="ttl">
  text<br>
  <span>column</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: try to add inline-css

Comment: Are you missing commas in the selectors, or is the h2 contained within the correct classes too?

<div class="kasoumv">
   <div class="text">
      <h2 class="ttl">
         text<br>
         <span>column</span>
      </h2>
   </div>
</div>

works as expected

Comment: are you talking about the text "column" in the `<span>`?

Comment: Its the "text" part.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the html snippet, it does not look like you need the other classes in the selector try just the `h2.ttl` selector.

```
<style>
* {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h2.ttl {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
</style>

<h2 class="ttl">
 text<br>
 <span>column</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied those long clases from the browser, I just updated now.

Comment: ok thanks - then I think we need to see your actual html and css files. it seems like the issue is something wrong with the files (missing a closing tag somewhere or a typeo)

Answer (score 0):

With the example you wrote it might seem the h2 is not being selected properly, but in case the h2 is inside the `kasoumv` and `text` classes you can try to force the style by using chaining the h2 class on itself:

```
h2.ttl.ttl
```

This is like using the !important attribute, but less hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Setting explicit font size on `*` is a very bad practice. It will always override sizes for children of any element. It's better to set it like this:

```
* {
 font-size: inherit;
}

body {
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

If you insist on having universal selector explicit font size, you can use

```
h2.ttl,
h2.ttl * {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```